# Remove all site collections under one specific path

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have a web application with 100 site collections under the /sites/ path.
Also a root site collection in the root /

I need a powershell script to delete all of them except the root site collection.

I know the powershell command is remove-spsite but I dont want to type 1000 urls

Comment: What does Get-SPSite give you?

Comment: ssss? Get-SPSite | Remove-SPSite

Comment: but how can I remove all of them under /sites only??

Comment: You should be able to make use of Get-SPSite to return all your sites, add an appropriate filter, then pipe the results through remove-spsite

Comment: damn you, if I am asking its because I need the syntax if I knew the syntax then I wouldnt ask :)

Comment: That's why I asked what Get-SPSite returned then we can work out what filters to apply in your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Get-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607950.aspx):   Returns all site collections that match the given criteria.

[Get-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607807.aspx):    Returns all subsites that match the given criteria.

[Remove-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607890.aspx): Completely deletes the specified Web.

By piping one command into the next you should be able to delete all web sites. The final whatif parameter shows what will happen.

```
Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb | Remove-SPWeb -whatif
```